# CSS Relative positioning preventing click on link

Tags: css

Please look at my jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/ftuZ5/ . I know why the links won't work as the relative positioning I have used to create the link / menu backgrounds I want is covering the a element but I can't work out how to resolve the issue (having tried relative and z-index on the li and a elements, plus adding and extra div to span the a element using that to create the 'button' style background) but all to no avail.

```
li {
    list-style: none;
}
.side-nav li {
  padding-bottom: 3.125em;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  text-align: center;
}
.side-nav a {
  position: relative;
  top: 1.75em;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #c7cbaf;
  -webkit-border-radius: 48px;
  -moz-border-radius: 48px;
  -ms-border-radius: 48px;
  -o-border-radius: 48px;
  border-radius: 48px;
  padding-top: 1.375em;
  padding-bottom: 0.75em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.responsive-side-nav {
  background: transparent url(http://thewebbakery.co.uk/assets/graphics/responsive-icon-sml.png) no-repeat top center;
}

.interactive-side-nav {
  background: transparent url(http://thewebbakery.co.uk/assets/graphics/interactive-icon-sml.png) no-repeat top center;
}

.ux-side-nav {
  background: transparent url(http://thewebbakery.co.uk/assets/graphics/ux-icon-sml.png) no-repeat top center;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution for you:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftuZ5/10/)

```
<nav class="side-nav" role=navigation>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><div id="responsive-side-nav" class="side-nav-image"></div>Responsive Web Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div id="interactive-side-nav" class="side-nav-image"></div>Interactive Web Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div id="ux-side-nav" class="side-nav-image"></div>User Experience</a></li>
</ul>
```

By wrapping the anchor tags around a new div for the images, the whole thing becomes clickable.

Then you can position the images as you wish (I've created a common class for each image):

```
.side-nav-image
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

The only downside to this is that the hit area for the button increases to fit the size of the image. But if you want the image to overlap, while having the whole thing clickable, I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: Thank you - that works. I was concerned that the div inside the a tag would render the css invalid but it appears not to

Comment: Glad to hear. Maybe worth noting that in HTML4 , you should't put block elements inside an anchor tag, but with HTML5 it's fine!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the height and the width on the  tags, if you display them as "blocks"

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't work (it puts the icon behind the link background which is exactly what I didn't want) plus you don't have to set the height and width when displaying with block